# Git ignoring a file but not ones with names

Tags: git, gitignore

In my `.gitignore` file I want to ignore a file just called `.env` but not files that have `something.env`:

I have tried this:

```
.env
!*.env
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you simply ignore `.env`. Thus your `.gitignore` reads:

```
.env
```

(only one line)

It will not ignore anything with the `.env` extension.

Example (console):

```
$ echo 'foo' > .env
$ echo 'foobar' > foo.env
$ git add .; git commit -am "foobar"
[master 49d6a00] foobar
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 foo.env
```

Comment: Sorry it was my misunderstanding, I see now.

Comment: @OrbiterFleet: well the question-form of the answer is because some people simplify their problem to make it of reasonable size. There can be reasons why it is not possible. If not, I think this is a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `.env` in your `.gitignore` file

**.gitignore**

```
.env
```